# How to show document preview in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need a help to show the document's preview on the UI. It may be any kind of files(eg:.png, .jpeg, .txt, .pdf ...). When we click the download link from the angular client i need to open a dialog box with the file content as a preview to the user. We need something like gmail attachment. How to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: add Your code, what you have tried so for?

Answer (score 0):

Try something. When you end up in trouble and you have some `code to show` and you need help with `specific problem`, then come back. This is not a place to ask people to do design work for you.